# React Native Expo - Can I write code for both - IOS and Android with Expo or why does boilerplate code has only separate code?

Tags: react-native, expo

Im just trying to figure out both react native and expo and wonder:

When I init a new project with expo, Im being directed to choosing a template. I can choose between the bare minimum and one that has more boilerplate code plus enabled typescript called "tabs". The boilerplate code for tabs has NO seperate code for IOS/android while the minimum temlate has code specifically for android and for ios so as I understand you must write everything double.

```
Why is it so different among these templates?!
```

Reading the react native docs: it says that there can be same code for both ios/android plus the use of Platform module/ platform-specific file extensions for cases where the code must differ. however as I understand it, its not the default.

```
Could someone explain to me why the expo minimum template suggests to write double code, having those 2 folders IOS and Android?!
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are not going to write the same code twice. React Native is all about writing in JavaScript. Even when you initialize your project with `React Native CLI` and not `Expo` you get those `android` and `ios` folders but you only code in your `.js` files. Of course, you can go further and edit those files and folders if you are familiar with mobile development since some functionalities (and React Native components) are only exclusive to one platform.

> React components wrap existing native code and interact with native
> APIs via React’s declarative UI paradigm and JavaScript.

You can learn more about it here: https://reactnative.dev/

Comment: ah are these IOS/android folders then like the build folders? will my js code that i write elsewhere be "copied" there in the end? Im still wondering why the one template didnt have these folders and the other did

Comment: Yes, they are the ones that contain the codes that will get published to the store. If you weren't using `React Native` you'd have to write in those specific languages like `Java` and `Swift`. These folders are what you get when you choose the `bare` React Native Expo config or when you use the `React Native CLI`.

Comment: Okay thank you and when I choose the expo template with a lot of boilercode - what is the reason that those folders dont exist? do you know that?

Comment: Well `expo` is there to get you up and running into `React Native` without worrying about Native code and that's why React Native itself recommends using it if one isn't familiar with Native codes and is new to mobile development: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: but both templates are expo templates. one with more, one with less code, which is why i am confused why one expo boiler code has those folders and the other - also expo- boilercode has - not-

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure but I guess that since they are just templates, they are included to be used by people who still wanna configure the Native code as well as have access to some of the tools that `Expo` provides. Using `Expo` gets you into coding much faster than `React Native CLI` since the latter requires a lot of configurations that take up to an hour to set up.